# Emacs complains: font 'serif 10' is not defined

Tags: emacs, fonts

I am running Linux Mint 12 and trying to start emacs but keep getting this error:

> font 'serif 10' is not defined

It seems obvious to me that I don't have the correct font. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to upgrade `fontconfig` to either re-validate itself and acquire the font anew or find another way to get this font.

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this font issue?

Comment: Fontconfig is a suite of font library tools; it may be related to your problem, but if so what you need is not to upgrade it but to configure it.

Comment: Does your `~/.emacs` make reference to `serif 10`? Which version of Emacs are you using?